# how to diff and merge with two branches if core.sparsecheckout set to true?

Tags: git

I have the following two compelte repositories:

```
# compelte foo bar
mkdir complete-foo && cd complete-foo
git init
mkdir foo
echo bar > bar
echo bar > foo/bar
git add bar foo 
git commit -a -m "complete foo bar"
cd ..
# deployed foo baz
mkdir deployed-foo && cd deployed-foo
git init
mkdir foo
echo baz > topbaz
echo bar > foo/baz
git add topbaz foo
git commit -a -m "deployed foo baz"
cd ..
```

and a sparse repository that tracks them:

```
mkdir sparse-bar && cd sparse-bar
git init
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo foo >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git remote add -f complete ../complete-foo
git fetch complete
git checkout -b complete complete/master
git remote add -f deployed ../deployed-foo
git fetch deployed
git checkout -b deployed complete/master
```

So far, so good.

Now I want to diff/merge only files inside *foo/* folder, but it does not really work as I expect it.

E.g. if I do,

```
echo boo >> foo/bar
git diff deployed..complete
```

I don't see the difference.

I would also like to learn how I can merge only the difference restricted only to foo/ and its children. I don't want to see the difference between

PS

Spend hours on trying "read-tree --prefix" approach to achieve something similar. Unsucceful.

Answer (score 0):

```
git commit foo/bar
git diff deployed..complete
```

.. it works.. **8-/**

```
diff --git a/foo/bar b/foo/bar
index 6a2d84d..5716ca5 100644
--- a/foo/bar
+++ b/foo/bar
@@ -1,2 +1 @@
 bar
-boo
```

and...

```
git checkout complete 
git merge deployed
```